# Recommendations for logger in Linux application

Tags: c++, linux, logging

I'm building a C++ Linux application and I need to log its activity. What are the existing Linux facilities to create logs? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html)?

Comment: Seems like Swiss-army knife logger...

Comment: Yep, it's nice and easy to set up and use, although I used port to .Net of this logger (log4net).

Answer (score 10):

The historic one is syslog(3).  From C:

```
#include <syslog.h>
openlog("myprogram", LOG_PID, LOG_LOCAL0);
syslog(LOG_INFO, "data %d %s", 3, "example");
```

From Perl:

```
use Sys::Syslog;
openlog "myprogram", "pid", "local0";
syslog 'info', 'data %d %s', 3, 'example';
```

From shell:

```
logger -p local0.info -t myprogram -- data 3 example
```

The syslogd daemon can be configured to put log files in different places (files, tty, other machines) depending on the facility (here `LOG_LOCAL0`) and the priority (here `LOG_INFO`)

Comment: Can syslog write to a separate file or it all goes to the syste log?

Comment: It goes to system log.  It can also log to the console with LOG_CONS.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Alex has said, why would you need a Linux specific logger?

Comment: It's not like I need Linux-specific logger. I just wanted to know what alternatives to manually logging to a file do I have on Linux platform.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. 'log4cxx' is the answer

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to  try out c-log,a fast ,stable and thread-safe log lib(logger) for C/C++ language,https://github.com/0xmalloc/c-log.